# Redemption throws error when attempting to call GetDefaultFolder with (RDOSession)session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderOutbox)

Tags: outlook-redemption

The following code does not work:

```
RDOSession session = RedemptionLoader.new_RDOSession();
session.Logon();
var folder = session.GetDefaultFolder(rdoDefaultFolders.olFolderOutbox);
```

this is the exception i got (Sorry its in german):

```
COMException: Error in IMAPISession::OpenMsgStore: E_UNEXPECTED
ulVersion: 0
Error: Der Informationsspeicher steht zurzeit nicht zur Verfügung.
Component: MAPI 1.0
ulLowLevelError: 0
ulContext: 649
   bei Redemption.IRDOSession.GetDefaultFolder(rdoDefaultFolders FolderType)
```

Outlookversion: 2019 MSO (16.0.10373_20050) 32-Bit / PST (no Exchange-Server)
Redemption: 5.19.0.5248

Any ideas what the problem cause?

Comment: Is this a standalone app? If Outlook running at the same time? If yes, do both apps run in the same security context (Run As Administrator etc.)?

Comment: Do you get the same results with OOM instead of RDO?